# com.capitalone.dashboard:UI ........................ FAILURE when trying to build Hygieia on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, gulp, hygieia

Following the steps @ https://hygieia.github.io/Hygieia/setup.html When executing $mvn clean install at location https://github.com/Hygieia/Hygieia.git /Hygieia
I get exception:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] com.capitalone.dashboard:Hygieia ................... SUCCESS [  2.123 s]
[INFO] com.capitalone.dashboard:UI ........................ FAILURE [ 15.798 s]
[INFO] com.capitalone.dashboard:ui-tests .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.529 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-29T13:37:10+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:gulp (gulp build) on project UI: Failed to run task: 'gulp build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 137 (Exit value: 137) -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:gulp (gulp build) on project UI: Failed to run task
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'gulp build' failed.
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:63)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.GulpMojo.execute(GulpMojo.java:64)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:94)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutionException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 137 (Exit value: 137)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:82)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(ProcessExecutor.java:64)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(NodeExecutor.java:29)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:58)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 137 (Exit value: 137)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:74)
    ... 27 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :UI
```

Versions:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1~14.04-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_222, vendor: Private Build
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
$ node -v
v8.16.2
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, it was the version of npm and nodejs, now since I am using ubuntu 14.04, it should be nodejs=v8.16.2 and npm=6.4.1 but for other versions of ubuntu it might be different. Here is the diff:

```
$ diff pom.xml pom.xml.ORG
75,76c75,76
<               <nodeVersion>v8.16.2</nodeVersion>
<               <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
---

>               <nodeVersion>v6.9.1</nodeVersion>
>               <npmVersion>5.0.1</npmVersion>
>
```

Comment: Everytime I am doing:
nvm install v8.11.0
gulp serve